# C# regex replace match regarding match length

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to replace numbers in a string with the `"N"` character. What I've done and works properly is:

```cs
    string str = "abc1234def";          
    str = Regex.Replace(g, @"\d+", "N");`
```

the output of the above will give `"abcNdef"` since the `"1234"` will be replaced with `"N"`. The aim now is to replace with `"N"` every single number so for the above input, the output would be `"abcNNNNdef"`.

Any help would be welcome

Comment: Remove the `+` quantifier. Haven't tested it, but makes sense as it wouldn't consider `1234` as a single match.

Comment: Do you have a requirement to use RegEx? Otherwise you write simple loop over string and replace every `.IsDigit()` char with N.

Comment: Is the first variable supposed to be `g` rather than `str`? You don't show `g` declared anywhere, but based on your expected output, that seems to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the + quantifier. Then each digit is considered separately, rather than as `1234` being a single match to replace.

```
str = Regex.Replace(g, @"\d", "N");
```

This is assuming that `g` is "abc1234def" and results in "abcNNNNdef" for `str`.

You can read more about the quantifiers in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string replacedText = Regex.Replace("abc1234def", @"([0-9]{1})", "N");
```

regular expression `"([0-9]{1})"` will match every single number separately and then `Replace` function will replace each match with `N`